# How to mock extension function or top level function in UI testing Before Android P?

Tags: android, mockito, powermock, ui-testing, mockk

**Is there any way to mock top level function or extension function in UI testing before Android P.**

In android UI test I have used mockk library but there is no support extension function mocking in UI test before Android P. Below is supported feature given by mockk(https://mockk.io/ANDROID.html).

[image]

Here is top level function file and it's UI test that works very well above Android P version but not worked before P because mockk is not supported.

```
@file:JvmName("Test")
package com.example.dexopener.mockk

fun isLogin(): Boolean {
    return false;
}
```

For above top level function Here in UI test mocking isLogin method that works very well after Android P

```
@Test
fun test_top_level_function_is_able_to_mock(){
        mockkStatic("com.example.dexopener.mockk.Test")
        every { isLogin() } returns true
        assertTrue(isLogin())
}
```

Comment: You want to mock this without Mockk and using other way?

Comment: As I mentioned Mockk is not supported to mock extension function in UI testing before API 29. So I am ok with other way, my main concern is to mock in UI testing before API 29